# Как прописать ссылку на email в html письме?

Tags: html, css

Привет! 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, никак не прикрепляются стили к ссылке на email в HTML письме, по умолчанию становится синей. 
Где ошибка?

```
<p style="padding-bottom: 31px;font-family: Arial; color: #c2c6c8; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.54px; text-align: left;">Вы получили это письмо, потому что согласились получать рассылку VINTAGE VOYAGE на адрес
  <a href="mailto:ya.ale91@yandex.ru" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block;font-family: Arial; color: #ffffff; font-size: 12px; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.54px; text-decoration: none;" title="ya.ale91@yandex.ru">ya.ale91@yandex.ru</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылку необходимо выносить из строчных элементов.

```
<span style="display: inline; font-family: Arial; color: #c2c6c8; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: 0.54px; text-align: left;">Вы получили это письмо, потому что согласились получать рассылку VINTAGE VOYAGE на адрес</span>
<a href="mailto:ya.ale91@yandex.ru" target="_blank" style="display: inline;font-family: Arial; color: #ffffff; font-size: 12px; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.54px; text-decoration: none;" title="ya.ale91@yandex.ru">ya.ale91@yandex.ru</a>
```